# Read Text file and display results in separate Labels C# Visual Studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to read a .txt file from the folder that the exe is in and display parts of the text file in multiple corresponding labels or RichtextBox's in a form.

**Dummy example:**
Text box contents: "b1.txt"

QuestionTitle="why did the chicken cross the road";

AnswerTitle[0]="It didn't";

AnswerTitle[1]="Who";

In the form I'd like when I hit search for it to display the following:

Label 1 - Question: why did the chicken cross the road

Label 2 - Answer 1: It didn't

Label 3 - Answer 2: Who cares

I've seen people use StreamReader and others use File.OpenRead. I'm not sure which is the best method for ready text from a text file and displaying specific text from the file to a specific label or richtextbox.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: go ahead with any one of the above(StreamReader and others use File.OpenRead) as you said  and come back if you are facing any trouble

Comment: Sorry one of the above what? Oh you mean StreamReader and or File.OpenRead. I've only seen them pull a whole text file. not parts of it so i've got nothing to go on here. I can pull a whole text file but not specific text as mentioned above so i do require help please.

Comment: @CurtisHumphreys try splitting your text into an array and then getting them one by one

Comment: @Virgil right so i'm pretty newby at all of this. I cannot change the formating of the text file as these files are being pulled from another program so they must remain in that format and i'm not sure what you mean by splitting my text into an array. I'm afraid maybe this question is to newby for this forum sorry.

Comment: Basically I want to do this but with C# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-HMR0ootSo. I can figure out the rest...

Comment: Read the whole text using either StreamReader or File.OpenRead, to a string. Then use String.Split function to split it by tabs and newline characters. String.Split will give you all lines in separate records.

Comment: Although, I would say, see if you can save the values in tabular format. Probably use an excel file. That will be faster than keeping a single text file.

Comment: @jitendragarg You'll be happy to know i tried exactly that and it worked! I beat you to the punch by a whisker! Works great. I'll post the code below below once i'm done and tested. Good to know i landed on the correct track

Comment: Good to know. Post the code as answer, for others. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split on a string you need to use the overload that takes an array of strings:

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you want to handle different types of line breaks in a text, you can use the ability to match more than one string. This will correctly split on either type of line break, and preserve empty lines and spacing in the text:

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then doing lines[0] will get you your question and lines[1] would be your first answer and so on.

Comment: The Environment.NewLine property contains the default newline for the system. For a Windows system for example it will be "\r\n".

Comment: Ahh that's a much more compact way of doing it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so i sorted it all out thanks for the help. Here's what to do. Note I'm only wanting to read every second line of the Text file hence the huge amount of strings that are place holders. I use the other text elsewhere.

> Blockquote

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace tester_import
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()

    {


        InitializeComponent();



    }

    private void qsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void qsearchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.ShowDialog();
        qsearchtxt.Text = of.FileName;

    }

    private void viewtxt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str1;
        string str2;
        string str3;
        string str4;
        string str5;
        string str6;
        string str7;
        string str8;
        string str9;
        string str10;
        string str11;
        string str12;
        string str13;
        string str14;
        string str15;
        string str16;
        string str17;
        string str18;
        string str19;
        string str20;
        string str21;

        string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir+"/" + minput.Text + ".txt");
        str1 = sr.ReadLine();
        str2 = sr.ReadLine();
        str3 = sr.ReadLine();
        str4 = sr.ReadLine();
        str5 = sr.ReadLine();
        str6 = sr.ReadLine();
        str7 = sr.ReadLine();
        str8 = sr.ReadLine();
        str9 = sr.ReadLine();
        str10 = sr.ReadLine();
        str11 = sr.ReadLine();
        str12 = sr.ReadLine();
        str13 = sr.ReadLine();
        str14 = sr.ReadLine();
        str15 = sr.ReadLine();
        str16 = sr.ReadLine();
        str17 = sr.ReadLine();
        str18 = sr.ReadLine();
        str19 = sr.ReadLine();
        str20 = sr.ReadLine();
        str21 = sr.ReadLine();

        question.Text = str1.Split('"')[1];
        answerone.Text = str2.Split('"')[1];
        answertwo.Text = str4.Split('"')[1];
        answerthree.Text = str6.Split('"')[1];
        answerfour.Text = str8.Split('"')[1];
        answerfive.Text = str10.Split('"')[1];
        answersix.Text = str12.Split('"')[1];
        answerseven.Text = str14.Split('"')[1];
        answereight.Text = str16.Split('"')[1];
        answernine.Text = str18.Split('"')[1];
        answer10.Text = str20.Split('"')[1];

        sr.Close();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the array example. :)